# How to batch save data driven graphics with a script in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, batch-processing, illustrator-scripting

I build data-driven graphics in Illustrator and am able to run a batch "Save to PDF" action on these graphics.

Can I do the batch "Save to PDF" action with a script instead? My thinking is that the script will have to loop through the datasets somehow, but unsure where to start.

Answer (score 4):

here's a sample showing how to loop thru the Datasets

```
var idoc = app.activeDocument;
var ds = idoc.dataSets;
var activeds = idoc.activeDataSet; // save the current dataset


for (i=0; i<ds.length; i++) {

    ds[i].display(); // this is the same as clicking the dataset arrows in the UI
    app.redraw(); // we don't need to redraw, it's here so you can see as they change

    doyourthing ();

    alert('data set: ' + i);
}

activeds.display(); // display the original active dataset

function doyourthing() {
    // save to pdf here
}
```